# Let $g'(x)$ be constant. Find the fifth derivative of $f\circ g(x)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question with some of my calculus homework. Here's the question:
Let $g'(x)$ be constant. Find the fifth derivative of $f\circ g(x)$.
First, is $f\circ g(x)$ just $fg(x)$? And how do I go about starting this question? 
If $g'(x)$ is a constant, would that mean $g(x)$ equals a number?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: example: what is the (first) derivative of $h(x) = 7 x - 53 \; \; ?$

Comment: 7? because the 53 becomes 'nothing' and we get rid of the x...

Comment: yes............

Comment: soo the idea is just to repeat that??

Comment: no, not the idea. I was worried that you did not seem to know what it meant for a derivative to be constant. I gave an example... Look at the answer by csch2

Answer (score 2):

First, integrate $g'\left(x\right)=c_1$ to get $g\left(x\right)=c_1x+c_2$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants. The composition $f\circ g\left(x\right)$ is then $f\left(c_1x+c_2\right)$. Let $h\left(x\right)=f\circ g\left(x\right)$. Differentiation of this is just repeated application of the chain rule:
$$h'\left(x\right)=c_1f'\left(c_1x+c_2\right)$$
$$h''\left(x\right)=c_1^2f''\left(c_1x+c_2\right)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$h^{\left(5\right)}\left(x\right)=c_1^5f^{\left(5\right)}\left(c_1x+c_2\right)$$

Comment: If you code something as ( \frac a b ) and it's displayed rather than inline you'll see $\displaystyle ( \frac a b),$ whereas with \left( \frac a b \right) you'll see $\displaystyle \left( \frac a b \right).$ However, with f(x) you'll see $f(x),$ and coding it as f\left(x\right) won't change it. And people seeing your code may think \left and \right are necessary. And it takes you longer to type it and makes editing it more complicated.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for pointing that out, I'm still somewhat new to TeX so I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $f\circ g(x) = f(g(x))$ is $$f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$
Can you take it from here?

Hint: You can take another derivative and not worry about taking the derivative of $g'(x)$ because it is a constant!
See [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$ by the Chain Rule. Let $g'(x)=c$ for some constant $c.$ Thus, we have
$$(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)=c\cdot f'(g(x)).$$
Claim that $$(f\circ g)^{(n)}=c^n\cdot f^{(n)}(g(x))$$ for all integers $n>0.$ Clearly, as we have shown above, this holds for $n=1.$
Now for the inductive step. Assume that $$(f\circ g)^{(n)}=c^n\cdot f^{(n)}(g(x)).$$ Then, we have
\begin{align*}
((f\circ g)^{(n)})'&=(c^n\cdot f^{(n)}(g(x)))'\\
&=(c^n)'\cdot f^{(n)}(g(x))+c^n\cdot (f^{(n)}(g(x)))'
\end{align*} by the Product Rule. Since $(c^n)'=0,$ we have
\begin{align*}
(c^n)'\cdot f^{(n)}(g(x))+c^n\cdot (f^{(n)}(g(x)))'&=0(f^{(n)}(g(x)))+c^n\cdot f^{(n+1)}(g(x))\cdot g'(n)\\
&= c^{n+1}\cdot f^{(n+1)}(g(x))
\end{align*} by the Chain Rule and that $g'$ is constant, which is want we want. Thus the inductive step is done. Putting in $n=5,$ the fifth derivative of $(f\circ g)$ is $c^5\cdot f^{(5)}(g(x))=\boxed{(g'(x))^5\cdot f^{(5)}(g(x))}.$
$\blacksquare$